# Passing PHP string to HTML href" attribute apostroph problem

Tags: javascript, quotes, syntax-error, apostrophe, double-quotes

I am trying to pass a string from a PHP variable to HTML

```
 <a href="javascript:deleteProduct('<?=addslashes($row['productName'])?>');"
```

The problem is with the apostrophes. The string might contain both single and double apostrophes ' and " , like in the following example:

```
<a href="javascript:deleteProduct('Richdel, 2400\', 1\", fi fara solenoid');"
```

It won't trigger the Javascript function due to the incorrect use of the apostrophes, syntax error. It processes as the \" would be the end of the href attribute's value.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?= htmlentities(addslashes($row['productName'])) ?>
```

will turn the `"`s into `&quot;`, so they'll go into HTML.

Comment: thank you. it works perfectly, even in javascript alert('[...]') :)

Answer (score 0):

A simple string replace will remove both types of quote entirely.

```
<?php echo str_replace("'", '', str_replace('"', '', $row['product'])); ?>
```

Comment: The goal is not to mangle the data.  If it's possible to escape the data (and it is), that's better than just removing it.

Comment: The goal of the example, presumably, is to create a link that deletes a product called `Richdel, 2400', 1", fi fara solenoid`.  Try doing that when you have no `'` or `"`.